# Is the set of functions obtained by acting a group on a function a basis for the vectorial space obtained by acting the group to the set itself?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm studying group theory for physics and I'm struggling with some concepts. Here's one.

According to the book "Semiconductors" by Yu et al. (p. 33):

> "One way to generate a representation for a group is to choose some function $f(x,y,z)$ and then generate a set of functions $\{f_i\}$ by applying the symmetry operations $O_i$ of the group to $f(x,y,z)$ so that $f_i =O_i[f]$. By definition a group has to satisfy the closure requirement. This means that when the operation $O$ is applied to $f_i$ the resultant function $O[f_i]$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the functions $f_i$:
> $$O[f_i] = \sum\limits_j{f_ja_{ji}}$$
> The coefficients $a_{ji}$ form a square matrix, which will be referred to as a transformation matrix. The set of transformation matrices of the form {$a_{ji}$} corresponding to all the operations in the group now forms a representation of the group."

To me it's not clear how the properties of the group allow for such an equation (the one with the sum) to be verified with a matrix (with elements $a_{ji}$) different from the identity matrix (which is trivial and would mean that there's only the identity element in the group), given any starting function $f$.
Could you, please, give me a proof of this equation, given the properties of a group? I tried but I always end up to the same conclusion, which is the trivial case I told you a few lines above.

EDIT: I think my question isn't 100% well formulated. The book never says that there must always be a set of matrices different from identity. I just want to be sure that, depending on the starting function, it's possible to get the identity matrix as only solution.

PS: by "properties" I mean the defining properties of a generic group, so associativity of elements, identity element, inverse of each element, closure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints which may clear it up sufficiently, otherwise complain and repost

The number of distinct linearly independent $f_i$ are usually fewer than the number of $O$. Imagine the function x and some space group in 3D, by completing the basis you will get y and z (maybe), but any group with more than 3 elements will give you a lot more options for $O[f_i]$ than there are distinct $f_i$.

The O will generally give you some linear combination of the basis f_i. For the example above a mirror plane 45 degrees from x will be represented by the expected matrix

$a_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Rotation by $\pi/8$ would give

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$

For more general functions you can end up with a lot of stuff, and if it's a bit random and structureless the $f_i$ can all be distinct, then you are right each of the $a_{ij}$ will be identity, because the f have no relation to the intrinsic symmetry. Usual applications are on polynomials of spatial variables, or things like atomic orbitals which have spherical or cylindrical symmetry, and transform into one another.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You start with a set of three functions and then you see that they verify the equation. What the book says, though, is that starting with a generic function and acting all the operators of the group on it, a set of functions is obtained which can be combined linearly to give all the function obtained by acting the group on these new functions themselves. Is it true, for any arbitrary starting function, if one imposes to use coefficients which form non-identity matrices?